# Android fully managed device use addOverrideApn method

Tags: android-management-api

With Android 12 and Android Management API i can use built-in Android Device Policy app to deploy policies on different devices.
No problem to enroll a new device or to push policies on it.

But i need to use **DevicePolicyManager@addOverrideApn** method to set custom APN on device. This method needs device owner permission in order to use it.

How can i use it without build a custom DPC?
Custom DPC was not encouraged by Google as mentioed here: https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/register

Can i use it via delegated scope application policy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, adding override APN is not yet supported in the Android Management API. Our Engineering team has created a related feature request for future review. Please note that the ticket is in our backlog for future consideration and has not been picked up for work. Therefore, we don't have any immediate plans or timelines associated with the request.

If you want to stay up to date with the latest updates for Android enterprise, we suggest that you join the [Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.